# UIView Height not fit for Customized Tabbar

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, swift4

I have a TabBar with custom class file. I need to change the TabBar height. When I increased TabBar height, UIView bottom hight not adjust according to TabBar. Bottom hidden behind the tab bar. Here is my code. Did I miss anything?

```
class TabbarController:
UITabBarController,UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    fileprivate lazy var defaultTabBarHeight = { tabBar.frame.size.height }()

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

        let newTabBarHeight = defaultTabBarHeight + 10.0

        var newFrame = tabBar.frame
        newFrame.size.height = newTabBarHeight
        newFrame.origin.y = view.frame.size.height - newTabBarHeight

        tabBar.frame = newFrame
    }
}
```

Comment: can you share how did you align your UIView also ?

Comment: Hi, UIView Is just a view in UIViewController. Do you need the screenshot?